# How to split a fraction into two Integers?

Tags: java, fractions

I'm working on a program where I need to create an object list from an external file containing fractions. I need to separate the numerator and denominator into two separate integers, without having the "/" be involved.

This is what I have so far:

```
while (fractionFile.hasNextLine()){

    num.add(fractionFile.nextInt());
    den.add(fractionFile.nextInt());

    }
```

I can't figure out how to have num.add read up until the "/" and have den.add read right after the "/"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May we see an outline of the file containing the fractions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String fraction="1/2";
String []part=fraction.split("/");  
num.add(part[0])
den.add(part[1])
```

Comment: calling split twice is not the most efficient way

Comment: I'm reading the fraction from an external file. How would I send the 2nd split to den?

Comment: share snapshot of ur file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to split the string using the desired pattern.

Comment: Would you explain how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (fractionFile.hasNextLine()){
   //If file contains
   // 1/2
   // 2/4
   // 5/6
    String line = fractionFile.nextLine();
    String split[]=line.split("/");
    num.add(Integer.parseInt(split[0])); // 1 stored in num
    den.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1])); // 2 stored in den
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have multiple fractions in your file seperated by a token (e.g. line brake, or `;`):

```
    String   input           = "1/2;3/4;5/6";
    String   token           = ";"
    String[] currentFraction = null;

    final List<Integer> nums   = new LinkedList<>();
    final List<Integer> denoms = new LinkedList<>();

    for (String s : input.split(token)) {
        currentFraction = s.split("/");
        if (currentFraction.length != 2)
            continue;

        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(currentFraction[0]));
        denoms.add(Integer.parseInt(currentFraction[1]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    Integer num = 0;
    Integer den = 0;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] str = sCurrentLine.split("/");
            if(str.length>2)throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not valid fraction...");

            num = num+Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
            den = den+Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        }

        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(den);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```